# Investigate absolute convergence of the integral $\int_0^\infty x^2\cos e^x\,dx$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, improper-integrals

I am studying absolute convergence of improper integral over $\left[0,+\infty\right)$
$$\int_0^\infty\!x^2\ \cos(e^x)\ dx$$
And I used the substitution 
$t=e^x$, I produce the improper integral
$$\int_1^\infty\frac{(\ln\ t)^2\cos\ t}t\ dt$$
Thank you for your corrections

Comment: Why would you use Dirichlet to study absolute convergence?

Comment: Because I don't know how the integral converge absolute while I could for conditionally convergence, that is my queation, how

Comment: See also [Riemann-Lebesgue lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann-Lebesgue_lemma).

Comment: The integral of the absolute value diverges.

Comment: @Lucian How could the RL lemma help?

Comment: @zhw.: The integrand is oscillating with a high frequency $($exponential even$)$, which only increases as *x* approaches infinity. The Riemann-Lebesgue lemma basically tells us that, as a consequence of this highly-oscillating behavior, the integral converges.

Comment: RL says if $f\in L^1,$ $\int f(t) e^{ixt}\,dt \to 0$ as $x\to \infty.$ That's a different thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The highly oscillatory term $\cos(e^x)$, which makes the integral convergent in the improper sense, does not help with absolute convergence at all. A typical way to show this is to use the inequality 
$$
|\cos t|\ge \cos^2 t = \frac12+\frac12\cos 2t
$$
where the constant term $1/2$ is what kills convergence. The second term, with $\cos 2t$, produces an improperly convergent integral.

Precisely: 
$$
\int_0^A x^2\cos e^x \,dx \ge  \frac12  \int_0^A x^2\,dx + \frac12  \int_0^A x^2\cos 2 e^x \,dx 
$$
where the first term obviously grows and the second is
$$
 \frac12 \int_0^A x^2 e^{-x} ( e^x \cos 2 e^x) \,dx 
$$
where  $x^2 e^{-x} $ decreases to zero (for large $x$) and the term in parentheses has a bounded antiderivative. Hence, the [Dirichlet test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirichlet%27s_test#Improper_integrals) applies to show that this has a limit as $A\to\infty$.